# Does finite type preserve finite dimensionality?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, krull-dimension

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of finite type of (Noetherian) schemes . Is $X$ of finite dimension when $Y$ is? Could you please provide a reference, or a counter example?

It is rather obvious when $Y$ is the spectrum of a field, but I am not sure how to approach it in general.

Comment: Can you do this when $X=\mathrm{Spec}B, Y=\mathrm{Spec} A$? Then, can you reduce to this case?

Comment: Keeping in line with Mohan's recommendation, I imagine this is true given that any finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian ring of dimension $n$ should have dimension bounded above by $n+$ (number of variables) which is necessarily finite. Im saying that this is an upper bound since any finitely generated algebra should look like some quotient of $R[x_1, \dots,x_n]$ and quotient rings should have smaller dimension.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the (well known I guess) statement $\dim R[X]=1+\dim R$ for a *noetherian* ring $R$.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question (maybe I should've thought about it longer before posting).